# How to build a Pandas Dataframe with a Numpy Array from Imported CSV data with multiple numbers

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm a little stumped on this one.  I've created a proof of concept where I built a Pandas Dataframe with a static Numpy Array of numbers.  I got this working fine, but now I'm taking it a step further and importing a CSV file to build this same Dataframe and Numpy Array.  Here is the snippet of the file and what I've written.  I want to take the second column of 'numbers' and build an array of 6 numbers per line.  For example, [[11],[21],[27],[36],[62],[24]], [[14],[18],[36],[49],[67],[18]], etc.

CSV:

```
date,numbers,multiplier
09/26/2020,11 21 27 36 62 24,3
09/30/2020,14 18 36 49 67 18,2
10/03/2020,18 31 36 43 47 20,2
```

CODE:

```
data = pd.read_csv('pbhistory.csv')
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.date, infer_datetime_format=True)
data.sort_values(by='date', ascending=True, inplace=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(data.numbers).to_numpy()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
print(df2.head())
```

ERROR:
I'm expecting 6 columns of data from df2 as I thought it was converted to an array properly after importing the 'numbers' column from the CSV, but I get the following:

**ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1414, 1), indices imply (1414, 6)**

So, I change the code to `df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['1'])` and get the following output.  The problem is, I need it to be in 6 columns, not 1.

```
                   1
0  11 21 27 36 62 24
1  14 18 36 49 67 18
2  18 31 36 43 47 20
```

So, as you can see, I'm only getting one column with all numbers, instead of an array of numbers with 6 columns.

Comment: The column 'numbers' is a series of strings, eg the first element is '11 21 27 36 62 24'. Split this into separate columns first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = pd.read_csv('pbhistory.csv')
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.date, infer_datetime_format=True)
data.sort_values(by='date', ascending=True, inplace=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(data.numbers).to_numpy()
```

Then split it first

```
df2 = df['numbers'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that CSV stands for Comma  Separated Values, ie it reads everything between two commas as one input. If you want the numbers separated you have to put commas between them, otherwise you'll have to parse the longer text of 6 non-comma separated values and rebuild the dataframe.